# how to use socket io in swift

Tags: ios, swift

> Error : 
>   Blockquote
>   it says "Argument labels '(String:)' do not match any available overloads"

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
    let socket = SocketIOClient(manager: URL(String:"http://localhost:8080") as! URL, nsp: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)])
//    let socket = SocketIOClient(manager: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")! as! SocketManagerSpec, nsp: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)])
override init() {
    super.init()

    socket.on("test") { dataArray, ack in
        print(dataArray)
    }

}
```

How can I solve this. 
any help would be apprciated.

Comment: Please paste your code with proper formatting so it'd really help others with readability also please go through the stack overflow guidelines on how to post a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read through the Socket IO documentation before trying to implement it. To get you started, you need to have a socketClient property in your Socket Manager class and you need to instantiate SocketClient before using Socket events.

```
class SocketManager {
  //Socket IO client instance to emit and observe events of your socket
  private let socketClient: SocketIOClient!

  private init() {
    let socketUrl = "Your Socket URL here"
    socketClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: socketURL)!)
    setupEvents()
  }

  func setupEvents() {
    socket.on("test") { dataArray, ack in
    print(dataArray)
  }

}
```

Hope this helps you get started

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommended below coding:

```
import SocketIO

let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket

socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
    print("socket connected")
}

socket.on("currentAmount") {data, ack in
    guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }

    socket.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
        socket.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
    }

    ack.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")
}

socket.connect()
```